# какую модель памяти сегментную или страничную использует windows, linux, macos?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, память

При прочтении Таненбаума возникли сложности с пониманием организации памяти в ОС. Какая модель используется в современных ОС? Сегментная, страничная, сегментно-страничная? В частности привело смущение сказанное про компиляторы, что для них использование сегментной организации памяти гораздо удобнее, но компилятор же запускается в ОС. Это и запутало. Как я понимаю как работать с  памятью реализовано в ОС, но разве программа может изменить этот способ?

Comment: в частности osx(у него ядро linux), gnu linux(и тут ядро linux),windows используют схему с виртуальной памятью и страничками.

Comment: @Naumov а разве виртуальная память не "надстройка" над этими видами? Сегментная вообще отсутствует в топ ОС? Если да то где она применяется в современности? Я почему то пришел к выводу, что используется сегментно-страничная. видимо надо перечитать всё еще раз, да и не раз.

Comment: Память может по разному выглядеть для разных частей. На уровне железа/ ОСи, страничная (paged) организация уже давно используется, к примеру x86-64 архитектура в long mode вообще segmentation не использует. @Naumov OS X производная (вдохновлённая) от BSD, а не Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- В современных ОС используется либо **страничная**, либо
  **сегментно-страничная** организация памяти.
  *Сегментная не выгодна с точки зрения рациональности использования физической памяти (возможна фрагментация).*

За всю работу по переводу логического адреса в физический ответственна аппаратура ( MMU ), а за формирование правил и таблиц по которым будет осуществлен перевод - ОС.

- *То есть, компилятор (и любая другая программа) не может перейти в другой режим адресования.*

***С точки зрения прикладной программы, она (программа) находится в линейном адресном пространстве размером около 2Гб (для 32 битной windows), так как, 2 ГБ виртуального адресного пространства занимает код ОС, драйверов и DLL.***

Хочу заметить, что **виртуальный адрес** не имеет ничего общего с **физическим**.

Очень утрированно процесс управления памятью показан на картинке ниже: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а конкретно для каждой ос не подскажете?

Comment: @borat_brata, Операционная система windows работает с сегментно-страничной организацией памяти. Сделано так из соображений практичности. Когда вы работаете с сегментом состоящем из страниц, вы получаете возможность выставлять защиту (привилегии) для однотипной области (для целого сегмента) и при этом не терять память на фрагментации (страницы всегда одинакового размера)