# Виртуальная память процесса в windows, что из неё видно и как меняются адреса?

Tags: windows, память, pe

Вопрос по загрузке PE и распределению в адресов в режиме пользователя.
Насколько я знаю, PE-секции выгружаются в общую для всех пользовательских программ область, в зависимости от доступности, и адреса задаются при загрузке в память, но тут вопрос - как происходит адресация внутри программы, раз мы не меняя кода получаем работоспособную программу и при этом можем через ту же память обращаться в адресное пространство других процессов? К примеру, у меня в программе по адресу 0x1 лежит `mov ax,bx` и когда происходит `jmp 0x1` он перекидывает меня именно в мою программу, а не в чужую, при этом я могу прочитать тот же 0x1 другой программы как?
И как бы мне выцепить user32 и kernel32 без таблицы импорта, но из своего pe-файла? И чего там ещё интересного можно найти?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Насколько я знаю PE-секции выгружаются в общую для всех пользовательских программ область в зависимости от доступности и адреса задаются при загрузке в память

Так было до Windows 3.1 включительно, когда виртуальной памяти попросту не существовало, и разделение производилось по отовсюду доступным сегментам. В современных же операционных системах каждый процесс находится в собственном, изолированном адресном пространстве («песочнице»).

Согласен, если файл (в том числе исполняемый) отображается в несколько процессов в режиме только на чтение и без каких-либо изменений, то операционная система *может* (но не обязана) сэкономить немного ОЗУ и отобразить соответствующие страницы *виртуальной* памяти этих процессов в один и тот же регион памяти *физической*.

Однако это всего лишь трюк на уровне отображения виртуальной памяти на физическую силами железа. С точки зрения самих программ никакого общего региона не существует.

> к примеру у меня в программе по адресу 0x1 лежит `mov ax,bx` и когда происходит `jmp 0x1` он перекидывает меня именно в мою программу а не в чужую

Перед тем, как переключить выполнение на какой-либо поток вашего процесса, операционная система производит определённую донастройку процессора. В частности, она извлекает из своих внутренних структур *физический* адрес карты отображения памяти и передаёт его специальному блоку процессора, *мапперу*.

Маппер же использует указанную карту примерно следующим образом:

[image]

*<sup>(Иллюстрация взята из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/578517/208074) на вопрос «Какую модель памяти сегментную или страничную использует windows, linux, macos?»)</sup>*

> при этом я могу прочитать тот же `0x1` другой программы как?

Надо попросить операционную систему не выделять пустую страницу, как она это обычно делает, а создать привязку к *уже существующей* странице. Иными словами, как бы прорубить окно в чужое адресное пространство.

Однако отображаемый блок не должен накладываться на уже занятый регион виртуальной памяти вашего процесса. С другой стороны, это окно можно создать в любом месте памяти вашей программы.

Для этого необходимо вызвать системную функцию [`MapViewOfFileEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366763(v=vs.85).aspx), указав целевой процесс и адрес в *его* виртуальной памяти.

> И как бы мне выципить user32 и kernel32 без таблицы импорта но из своего pe-файла?

`LoadLibrary()` + `GetProcAddress()`. Всё остальное — хаки и ненадёжно.