# Куда загружается DLL при её использовании процессом?

Tags: windows, dll

Среди преимуществ использования динамических библиотек перед статическими значится пункт экономии ресурсов системы, т.е. библиотека загружается в памяти единожды и используется сразу несколькими процессами (в смысле если библиотека уже загружена другим процессом, повторная загрузка выполняться не будет). Отсюда вопрос: куда же на самом деле загружается динамическая библиотека, если Windows позволяет использовать загруженный код нескольким процессам? В адресное пространство процесса? Но ведь тогда, когда процесс загрузивший DLL прекратить работу и выгрузится из памяти операционной системой, другой процесс потерпит фиаско!

Comment: Такой код https://pastebin.com/v1wjFE4j работает без проблем (ни разу не столкнулся с ошибкой). Хотя, по-хорошему, я обязан пользоваться LoadLibrary() вместо GetModuleHandle(). Скорее всего, LoadLibrary проверяет, загружена ли DLL или нет, - в этом и экономия.

Comment: Книга про Linux, но принципиальной разницы нет, поэтому, возможно будет для вас чем-то полезна: ["Компоновщики и загрузчики"](http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/algol/compilation/linkers-and-loaders-1.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Куда же на самом деле загружается динамическая библиотека, если Windows позволяет использовать загруженный код нескольким процессам? В адресное пространство процесса? Но ведь тогда, когда процесс загрузивший DLL прекратить работу и выгрузится из памяти операционной системой, другой процесс потерпит фиаско!

Верно. Поэтому для библиотек используется такой объект операционной системы, как *файловое отображение*. Упрощённо говоря, это буфер в физической памяти, отдельные части которого программы могут отображать в своё адресное пространство. Стоит отметить, что непосредственно буфер они не видят, он вне зоны их досягаемости; для создания отображения программы должны попросить об этом операционную систему.

Этот буфер может быть привязан к какому-то файлу, тогда его содержимое будет равно содержимому файла, и все изменения на одной стороне будет транслироваться на другую.

Также буфер может быть открыт в гибридном режиме, при котором его начальное содержимое копируется из файла, но дальнейшие изменения обратно не транслируются. Официально это называется Copy-on-Write, копирование при записи, — то есть при записи в участок файла поверх него как бы создаётся перехватывающая заплатка с копией содержимого этого участка.

Но самое главное — файловое отображение, как и файл, не принадлежит какому-то отдельному процессу, то есть это разделяемый ресурс. Если несколько программ запрашивают отображение одного и того же файла с одними и теми же правами доступа, они будут работать с одним и тем же отображением, не подозревая об этом. Соответственно и уничтожение этого буфера с закрытием соответствующего файла произойдёт только после закрытия всех его экземпляров у всех процессов-пользователей.

С точки зрения операционной системы это выглядит так:

[image]

*<sup>Виртуальная памяти процессов — физическая память — файл на диске. Иллюстрация взята из статьи «[File Mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366556(v=vs.85).aspx)» в MSDN</sup>*

Теперь о том, как это применимо к библиотекам и многократно запущенным программам. 
Сначала загрузчик просто открывает исполняемый файл. Затем он читает его заголовок и для каждой его секции создаёт отдельное файловое отображение с правами, указанными в заголовке этой секции: для кода, ресурсов, константных данных и изменяемых данных. Причём последнее отображается в режиме Copy-on-Write, чтобы у каждой программы библиотека обладала собственным набором переменных.

---

Выше я написал упрощённое объяснение, необходимое для понимания концепции. Теперь расскажу о том, как всё это работает на низком уровне.

Как я уже писал, работа буфера обеспечена куском физической памяти, фрагменты которого отображаются на виртуальную память процессов. Иными словами, когда программа просит операционную систему создать отображение с такими-то правами доступа для такого-то участка такого-то файла, операционная система модифицирует некоторые записи в таблице соответствия, в результате чего какой-то ранее нечитаемый диапазон страниц адресного пространства начинает отображаться на участок внутри буфера.

Это возможно благодаря принципам организации работы виртуальной памяти:

[image]

*<sup>(Иллюстрация взята из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575434/208074) на вопрос «Какую модель памяти сегментную или страничную использует windows, linux, macos?»)</sup>*

Именно указатель на начало этого диапазона и возвращают функции `MapViewOfFile()` на Windows и `mmap()` на Linux.

Comment: Процесс, впервые загружающий конкретную DLL, получает адрес из `LoadLibrary`, но откуда другие процессы узнают адрес расположения этой DLL в памяти?

Comment: @D.Stark Тоже от `LoadLibrary`. А она, в свою очередь, - от ядра ОС, которое и управляет отображениями файлов.

Comment: @D.Stark Перечитал свой ответ спустя прошедшую пару лет и понял, что там было много мелочей, не дающих общего понимания картины. Так что переписал его почти что с нуля; надеюсь, сейчас получилось понятнее.

Comment: Ещё вот интересна проблема передачи указателей на динамически выделенную память из библиотечных функций. Стоит задать отдельный вопрос?

Comment: @D.Stark, да, т. к. это уже другая тема, отличная от загрузки.

Comment: [malloc в DLL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1036040/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-malloc%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-dll)