# Почему нельзя передавать "malloc'нутые" значения из DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, malloc

Если в библиотечной функции выделяется блок динамической памяти, передача указателя в загрузившее эту библиотеку приложение может привести к неприятным последствиям. С чем это связано?

Я конечно понимаю, что у загруженной DLL будет свой менеджер памяти, и загружаться она будет в область разделяемой памяти. Это значит, что переменные, объявляемые в ней будут хранится в каком то своём стеке, а динамически выделяемая память расположена в своей "куче". `malloc` внутренне, вроде как, хранит сколько он памяти выделил и где, поэтому при вызове `free`, если менеджер памяти тот же, тоже знает расположение этой информации и знает сколько памяти освободить. Таким образом, при передаче указателя на память, выделенную в DLL, `free` не будет знать сколько памяти освободить.

В принципе, возвращаемый библиотечной функцией указатель можно использовать в любой программе, запущенной на той же машине?

Comment: думаю играет роль область видимости, у каждого из процессов свой диапазон куч и стека) для того что бы разные процессы могли использовать один кусок памяти есть IPC

Comment: @noname2019  DLL - это тот же процесс что и вызвавшая его программа, для каждого процесса создается экземпляр стека... а в ряде случаев для каждого потока. API Windows куда богаче чемСи-шная концепция областей видимости. Тут есть и объекты привязанные к потокам, и объекты принадлежащие нескольким процессам.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вопрос сформулирован бессмысленно. Никакого "нельзя" тут не существует и никогда не существовало. Вы можете передавать в/из DLL любые указатели. Никаких противопоказаний для  этого нет - это фундаментально необходимая возможность и отказываться от нее вам никто не предлагает.

> передача указателя в загрузившее эту библиотеку приложение может привести к неприятным последствиям

Сама передача указателя НЕ может привести к неприятным последствиям. Попытка *освобождения* указуемой памяти на территории другого модуля может. У загруженной DLL *может быть* свой менеджер памяти. А может и не быть. Это зависит от конфигурации этой DLL.

Это единственная деталь, которую нужно помнить: не предполагайте, что вы имеете право напрямую уничтожать объекты, выделенные внутри DLL. Вполне может оказаться так, что все объекты, созданные в DLL, должны передаваться обратно в DLL для уничтожения.

Answer (score 4):

Это возможно, но этого не делают. Причина может быть в том что библиотека и вызывающий ее модуль могут использовать разные аллокаторы, а потом вы воспользуетесь своим деаллокатором в вызывающем модуле? А если этот модуль - тоже библиотека, и указатель был передан выше?

Эти библиотеки обладают своими методами отслеживания ресурсов, и глобальные объекты для выполения этих функций разные , если аллокаторы разные. Какие именно - зависит от компилятора и его версии\сборки. Даже если в конечном итоге все они вызывают GlobalAlloc\GlobalFree.

Вызовы разных версий библиотеки времени исполнения обращаются к разным экземплярам фунций. А это, как история показала, в случае с майкрософтской библиотекой приводит к нарушению целостности кучи. Область памяти размещенной с помощью 8й студии не удалится вызовом функции из библиотеки 10й студии, и т.п.  DLL была откомпилирована в 8 а программа - в 10й. Иногда даже номера сборок имели значение.

Хорошим тоном является либо предоставление механизма создания и уничтожения объекта, либо, что предпочтительнее, выделение памяти вызывающим. Последний исключает всякую возможность того, что менеджер памяти из DLL будет конфликтовать с программой.
.