# Прекращение работы программы(C++)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int *pv = (int*)0x1d1510; // этот адрес вызывает "Перкращение работы программы" почему?
cout << *pv;
return 0;
}
```

Я пытался изменить этот адресс,кто-то знает как без вылета программы и без использования функции VirtualAlloc это зделать?
И еще как изменить значение по абсолютному адрессу в C++? И еще хотел добавить:адрес на который я указываю это переменная которая находиться в куче и это тестовая программа,мне надо изменнить значение этой переменной,эта переменная находиться вне программы,но при этом в куче!

Comment: запустите программу с правами админа

Comment: И еще хотел добавить:адрес на который я указываю это переменная которая находиться в куче и это тестовая программа,мне надо изменнить значение этой переменной

Comment: - Andrio Skur я же с паматью работаю иными словами:пытаюсь без пропуска пройти в клуб

Comment: т. е. вы хотите  иметь возможность так легко  брать любой адрес  и делать с ним что хочется, и чтоб компилятор этого вам позволял. Лихо!

Comment: А как изменять тогда значение адреса может Win API в помощь(мне)?

Comment: и вобще как отвечать на коментарии?

Comment: @fvBn, нужно перед ником поставить `@`, чтобы человеку пришло оповещение о вашем комментарии.

Comment: Вы хотите изменить память _другой_ программы, что ли?

Comment: А как вы вообще получили этот адрес?

Comment: @VladD да,верно!

Comment: @Harry я может не ясно выразился,но сказал что запустил другую(тестовую) програму и там переменная имела тот адрес причем она находилась в куче(указатель на адрес в куче)

Comment: Вот! На это я и намекал. Адрес в адресном пространстве одной программы вообще-то не имеет никакого отношения к адресу в адресном пространстве другой программы. Более того, этот адрес даже может теоретически совпасть с каким-нибудь адресом в вашей программе :) Так что даже если бы это было можно - вы все равно попадаете "пальцем в небо". А вообще, если б это было вообще можно в современных операционках - то ни о каких там, скажем, банковских приложениях и говорить было бы нельзя - любой пацан мог бы миллионы воровать :)

Answer (score 5):

Ваша программа, очевидно, выполняется на платформе с виртуальной памятью (к которым относятся в том числе и настольные компьютеры под управлением современных ОС).

Все адреса, с которыми вы работаете в вашей программе, — это адреса виртуального адресного пространства пространства, то есть *воображаемой* памяти. В эту память нельзя ничего записать и из нее нельзя ничего прочитать, потому что этой памяти изначально не существует, пока вы не «материализуете» соответствующий участок адресного пространства при помощи соответствующих функций системного API (`VirtualAlloc` и т. п.). Без этого ни о каком «изменить значение по абсолютному адресу» не может быть и речи, ибо никакой памяти по этому адресу нет и никакого значения не существует.

Comment: Проблема ещё глубже: ТС хочет доступиться к адресу в адресном пространстве _другой_ программы.

Comment: @VladD верно!!!

Answer (score 4):

Если вы запускаете программу на Windows или Linux — у вас нет прямого доступа к физической памяти, она «виртуализируется» через назначенную вашему процессу таблицу трансляции адресов:

[image]

*<sup>(Иллюстрация взята из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/578517/208074) на вопрос «Какую модель памяти сегментную или страничную использует windows, linux, macos?»)</sup>*

Таблица эта, в свою очередь, управляется операционной системой и напрямую вашей программе недоступна.

Чтобы получить возможность доступа к определённому адресу, надо его куда-то отобразить (то есть сопоставить ему что-то и назначить права доступа). Сопоставлять можно оперативной памяти (`VirtualAlloc()`), либо смещению внутри какого-то файла (`MapViewOfFile()`). При этом привязка производится с точностью до *страницы* — одного из множества последовательно идущих блоков определённого размера (как правило 4КБ).

Однако встаёт вопрос: а нужен ли вам доступ к произвольному региону? На момент запуска процесса у вас уже отображены образ исполняемого EXE-файла (с кодом и статическими данными) и куча (для динамически создаваемых данных). В образе хранятся глобальные переменные, и так доступные без знания их адреса, а при выделении памяти в куче вы получаете относительно случайный адрес, которым и надо пользоваться в дальнейшем.

Но даже если вы скомпилируете программу для чего-нибудь без виртуальной памяти (DOS, 16-битный Windows, микроконтроллеры) — кто даст гарантию, что по указанному вами адресу `0x1d1510` уже не будут лежать чьи-то данные, распечатывать которые безопасно, а вот изменять — уже нет?

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите. Как уже расписано в других ответах, под Windows (а у вас, исходя из `<windows.h>`, именно эта платформа), как и под многими другими операционными системами, каждый процесс работает с *виртуальной* памятью: адреса имеют смысл только внутри самого процесса. Для того, чтобы записать в адрес внутри *другого* процесса, необходимо воспользоваться системно-зависимыми функциями.

Для Windows это функция WinAPI [`WriteProcessMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx). Вот вам небольшой пример двух программ, где вы из одного экземпляра программы изменяете память другого экземпляра:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include "Windows.h"

volatile int value = 0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Process id = 0x" << std::hex << GetCurrentProcessId() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address of value = 0x" << (void*)&value << std::dec << std::endl;
    while (true)
    {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
        std::cout << "value is " << value << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Это программа печатает адрес переменной `value`, а потом в бесконечном цикле выдаёт её значения.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Windows.h"

bool update_value(DWORD pid, size_t address, int value)
{
    std::cout << "Updating value at process 0x" << std::hex << pid <<
                 ", address 0x" << address << " to " << std::dec << value << std::endl;

    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, FALSE, pid);
    if (handle == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't open process" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    bool result = true;

    if (!WriteProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)address, &value, sizeof(int), NULL))
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't write to process memory" << std::endl;
        result = false;
    }

    if (!CloseHandle(handle))
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't close handle" << std::endl;
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 4)
    {
        DWORD pid;
        size_t address;
        int value;

        std::stringstream s1(argv[1]), s2(argv[2]), s3(argv[3]);
        if ((s1 >> std::hex >> pid) &&
            (s2 >> std::hex >> address) &&
            (s3 >> std::dec >> value))
        {
            return update_value(pid, address, value) ? 0 : 1;
        }
    }

    std::cerr << "Cannot read parameters" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Вторая программа получает с командной строки id другого процесса, адрес в нём и новое значение, и записывает в другой процесс по этому адресу новое значение.

У меня получился такой вывод на экран:

Первая программа:

```
...\WriteProcessMemoryTest\x64\Debug>Target.exe
Process id = 0x1ec4
Address of value = 0x00007FF76DA07620
value is 0
value is 0
value is 0
value is 0
value is 0
value is 0
value is 1
value is 1
value is 2018
value is 2018
value is 2018
value is 65538
value is 65538
value is 65538
^C
```

Вторая программа:

```
...\WriteProcessMemoryTest\x64\Debug>Updater.exe 0x1ec4 0x00007ff76da07620 1
Updating value at process 0x1ec4, address 0x7ff76da07620 to 1

...\WriteProcessMemoryTest\x64\Debug>Updater.exe 0x1ec4 0x00007ff76da07620 2018
Updating value at process 0x1ec4, address 0x7ff76da07620 to 2018

...\WriteProcessMemoryTest\x64\Debug>Updater.exe 0x1ec4 0x00007ff76da07620 65538
Updating value at process 0x1ec4, address 0x7ff76da07620 to 65538
```

---

Важное замечание. В моём примере всё произошло так гладко только потому, что переменная `value` была объявлена как `volatile`. Это говорит компилятору, что он не имеет права кешировать значение этой переменной в регистрах, не имеет права применять к ней обычные оптимизации (например, заметить, что она не меняется в программе, и не перечитывать её значение). В случае, когда по адресу, который вы меняете, расположена обычная переменная, значение, которое вы записываете, может быть проигнорировано. Ну а если вы при записи «промахнётесь», с хорошими шансами вы обрушите программу, в которой производите изменения.

Comment: Хотел ли автор вопроса взаимодействовать с другими процессами? Его скорее заинтересовала невозможность даже доступа к произвольному адресу памяти.

Comment: @Arhad: Я его специально переспросил в комментариях.

Comment: @Arhad: Ну и про виртуальную память уже есть другие ответы, так что мне осталось только рассказать, а что же делать.

Comment: `Я его специально переспросил в комментариях` — увидел, спасибо.